# app is retreiving data but not images in firebase on real device

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

App is retrieving data but not images when I run app on real device but on emulator it works well and also retrieving images also.
Here are the screenshot of emulator [image: screenshot of emulator]
and the screenshot of real device [image: screenshot of real device]

**here below is the home.java code**
the below code is the home.java which is showing data but no image on real device but works fine on emulator.

```
    package com.food.sheenishere.stark;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.food.sheenishere.stark.Common.Common;
import com.food.sheenishere.stark.Interface.ItemClickListener;
import com.food.sheenishere.stark.Model.Category;
import com.food.sheenishere.stark.ViewHolder.MenuViewHolder;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class home extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference category;
    TextView txtFullName;


    RecyclerView recycler_menu;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Category,MenuViewHolder> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("Menu");
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        progressDialog.show();


        //init firebase
        database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        category=database.getReference("Category");




        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               Intent cartIntent = new Intent(home.this, Cart.class);
                startActivity(cartIntent);
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        //set name for user
        View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        txtFullName = (TextView)headerView.findViewById(R.id.txtFullName);
        txtFullName.setText(Common.currentUser.getName());





        //load menu
recycler_menu=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_menu);
        recycler_menu.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recycler_menu.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        loadMenu();
     //   progressDialog.dismiss();
    }

    private void loadMenu() {

        adapter =new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Category, MenuViewHolder>(Category.class,R.layout.menu_item,MenuViewHolder.class,category) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(MenuViewHolder viewHolder, Category model, int position) {
               viewHolder.txtMenuName.setText(model.getName());
                Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load(model.getImage())
                        .into(viewHolder.imageView);
                final Category clickItem = model;
progressDialog.dismiss();
                viewHolder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void OnClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick) {
                        //get category and send t new activity
                        Intent foodList=new Intent(home.this,FoodList.class);
                        //becox category id is key , so we just get key of this item
                        foodList.putExtra("CategoryId", adapter.getRef(position).getKey());
                        startActivity(foodList);
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        recycler_menu.setAdapter(adapter);

    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {


        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_menu) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_cart) {
Intent cartIntent= new Intent(home.this,Cart.class);
            startActivity(cartIntent);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_orders) {
            Intent orderIntent= new Intent(home.this,OrderStatus.class);
            startActivity(orderIntent);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_log_out) {

       Intent signin = new Intent(home.this,SignIn.class);
            signin.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(signin);

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have some code to share with us?

Comment: sir @TDG I have edited my question with java code

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the image you are loading is of high resolution and hence when you load it in your phone, Picasso can't process it.

For example if your image has a resolution of 4000 * 4000 and you load it in your phone which has screen resolution of 1080 * 1920, you are just wasting your resources and you should resize the image for better eficiency.

You should consider resizing your image as shown below:

```
 Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load(model.getImage()).resize("some lower resolution like 500 * 500")
                    .into(viewHolder.imageView);
```